# Document Library Open Document read-only

Tags: document-library

How can I allow uses to download a document in a document library as read-only rather than check-out? The 'email a link' option in the ribbon has the correct URL in it, but I would like to have a button that links to the file and so downloads it. 'Download a copy' is not the same, as it actually downloads, no option just to just open it directly. Plus this option is not in the ribbon when you are viewing a documents details.

**Update:**
The list view has been configured to make the 'title' field clickable and show the 'display' form (using `<FieldRef Name="Title" LinkToItem="TRUE"/>` since there doesn't seem to be a `LinkToDocument` option). I would like the form that shows up to have a link to the document (or a button in the ribbon). I tried `<a href="{@FileLeafRef}"><xsl:value-of select="@Title" /></a>`, but that is no good since it does not take into account the folder the file may be stored in.

Answer (score 1):

Override the document library permissions and set the desired users/group to be read only.  Change the view of the page to use either the Name (for use in Forms) or Name (linked to Document) column.

Is that what you're looking for or am I missing what you're trying to do?

Comment: I would like to do 'Title (link to document)', but that does not seem to be an option - more user friendly than opening a form and then the user figuring out how to open it (doing a a custom display form does not include a link to the document).

Comment: Title (link to document) exists in lists, not libraries.